# Is gravity weak or spacetime enormesly rigid?

Tags: gravity, spacetime

I was reading those links :

- [Link1](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/life-unbounded/just-how-resilient-is-spacetime/)
- [Link2](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01562662/document)

I was amazed about the novel notion of 'rigidity' in spacetime, it turned out that spacetime is enormesly rigide and to curve it to an appreciable amount we need huge amount of stress (mass).

My question is : why we are calling gravity a weak force when spacetime is extremely rigide? can I answer the question of the weakness of gravity by the answer 'No, gravity is not weak, it is just spacetime too rigid'?

Comment: Have you considered that gravity is simply weak in comparison to the other fundamental forces?

Comment: The strong, weak, and electromagnetic forces have enough power that they bind the basic subatomic particles together. Gravity, by contrast, has a much more far-reaching effect, but isn't as strong.

Comment: Since the only known way to curve space time is with stress, energy and momentum distributions it doesn’t make much sense to ask whether gravity is strong or weak based upon GR alone.  We must have a comparison with another force to gauge gravity’s strength.  This is done by comparing gravity to forces such as electromagnetism.  In such a comparison, gravity comes out on the short end of the stick.

Comment: Polhode is correct. Another way of putting this is that it only makes sense to ask why dimensionless universal constants have the values they have. Dimensionful constants, such as c and G, have the values they have simply because of our choice of a system of units.